# python unable to parse JSON Data

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am unable to parse the JSON data using python.

A webpage url is returning JSON Data

```
import requests
import json  

BASE_URL = "https://www.codechef.com/api/ratings/all"
data = {'page': page, 'sortBy':'global_rank', 'order':'asc', 'itemsPerPage':'40' }
r = requests.get(BASE_URL, data = data)
receivedData = (r.text)
print ((receivedData))
```

when I printed this, I got large text and when I validated using https://jsonlint.com/ it showed **VALID JSON**

Later I used

```
import requests
import json    

BASE_URL = "https://www.codechef.com/api/ratings/all"
data = {'page': page, 'sortBy':'global_rank', 'order':'asc', 'itemsPerPage':'40' }
r = requests.get(BASE_URL, data = data)
receivedData = (r.text)
print (json.loads(receivedData))
```

When I validated the large printed text using https://jsonlint.com/ it showed **INVALID JSON**

Even if I don't print and directly use the data. It is working properly. So I am sure even internally it is not loading correctly.

is python unable to parse the text to JSON properly?

Comment: You decoded the JSON and printed a text representation of a Python dictionary, which is not necessarily the same as the original JSON encoding.

Comment: The fact that you are getting any output from your second script is proof that Python is parsing the JSON just fine; you just aren't outputting JSON to the validator.

Comment: Even if I don't print and directly use the data. It is working properly. So I am sure even internally it is not loading correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short, `json.loads` converts from a Json (thing, objcet, array, whatever) into a Python object - in this case, a Json Dictionary. When you print that, it will print as a itterative and therefore print with single quotes..

Effectively your code can be expanded:

```
some_dictionary = json.loads(a_string_which_is_a_json_object)
print(some_dictionary)
```

to make sure that you're printing json-safe, you would need to re-encode with `json.dumps`

Answer (score 1):

When you use python's `json.loads(text)` it returns a python dictionary. When you print that dictionary out it is not in json format.

If you want a json output you should use `json.dumps(json_object)`.